# Adobe Acrobat DC Text Field Properties

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I was wondering if anyone happens to know how to change the list of fonts at the top of your font choice in Acrobat Text Field Properties??

[image]

It has been bugging me for a while as I want to put different fonts at the top of the list to streamline my work when changing fonts when preparing forms in Acrobat. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you hack deep into Acrobat, you can't rearrange the font drop down.

Comment: Thanks Max, do you happen to know how difficult or easy it might be to hack deep in to Acrobat to do this?

Comment: The "hack deep in to Acrobat" was more a rhetoric statement…